# How to correctly hash 'em dash' character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sha512

I am comparing hash values between Azure Databricks and SQL Server but get some unexpected results for non-ASCII characters. I have the problem narrowed down the the 'em dash' character (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm).

In **T-SQL** the character can be represented by `NCHAR(8212)`, this is confirmed by

`CASE WHEN '—' = NCHAR(8212) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Hashing the character using the `HASHBYTES` function with `algorithm='SHA2_512'`

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(128),HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NCHAR(8212))), 2)`)

results in the value:

`CABC0F199E27BC609E318E283A7CC3882599B1538EE7794082FD17AA6F4B32A3FF6B7169D87CA21D0DFD122C4D4D54E4CC40BF1F940489A2561C725A362B8A80`.

Following the same process in **Azure Databricks** using the string representation `'\u2014'`. And confirming this by

`CASE WHEN '—' = '\u2014' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Applying the `SHA2` function to the character with `bitLength=512`

`SHA2('\u2014', 512)`

results in

`48bf9ce5ab3755bf779032043c2ff6b0b075ec3407b3e473872ea2b059165a86bd70e0854ff6e9d05f1677a77fefcce7c6e3d73d1f3d9dd6488a2fecf041bb89`

Pasting the character in online editors, such as https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha512.html, https://www.conversion-tool.com/sha512/, https://codebeautify.org/sha512-hash-generator and https://sha512.online/, results consistently in

`48bf9ce5ab3755bf779032043c2ff6b0b075ec3407b3e473872ea2b059165a86bd70e0854ff6e9d05f1677a77fefcce7c6e3d73d1f3d9dd6488a2fecf041bb89`

The same value as in Azure Databricks.

This makes me believe that the issue is with SQL Server. Are there any suggestions on how to make SQL Server hash this character 'correctly'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash value is based on the binary representation of the string.

The following

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(128),
            HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NCHAR(8212) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8))
            , 2)
```

Returns the hash value you are after (using a UTF8 collation).

[You are after](https://dbfiddle.uk/-sU6A47s)

```
SELECT  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 0xE28094)
```

Some example results (showing method A yields the desired binary result to hash)

```
SELECT 
   A = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NCHAR(8212) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)),
   B = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), NCHAR(8212) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS)),
   C = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), NCHAR(8212))
```

Returns

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0xE28094 | 0x97 | 0x1420 |