# Hash a string as integer in T-SQL and Databricks SQL

Tags: t-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

For BI specific operations, I need to transform a varchar into hash (integer) in both T-SQL and Azure Databricks SQL.

There are specific functions in T-SQL like `CHECKSUM`, `HASHBYTES`, but they don't give the same result as `hash` function in Azure Databricks SQL.

Comment: They do, likely you aren't hashing the same value. For example, a very common error is that people seem to think that the hash of an ANSI, UTF-8 and UTF-16 string will result in the same hash; they *don't*. `SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','abc') AS AnsiHash, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',N'abc') AS UnscHash;`

Comment: [Try adding a `COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089741/73226)

Comment: @ThomA, you're right, I was able to hash and get the same value in Azure Databricks and T-SQL, but not I need to convert that binary to int into Azure Databricks SQL.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to convert it to an `int`, @bjnr . For the SHA2_256 hash of a value like `'a'` you get `0xCA978112CA1BBDCAFAC231B39A23DC4DA786EFF8147C4E72B9807785AFEE48BB`, which is *far* too large for even a `bigint`.

Answer (score 2):

My Understanding is to convert the **MD5** Hash values to Int can be done with the **CRC32.**
Need to cast the MD5 hash value with the **CRC32**.

For example I have created a table with below schema. in azure Databricks

```
%sql
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE Hash2int (
  id INT,
  name STRING,
  hash_value STRING
);
```

[image]
As you can see the hash_value is the String data type.

[image]

Using the Update statemet the hash_value column with **CRC32** converted values.

[image]

Hash Value are now converted to Integer datatype.

[image]
I have created a UDF for the use of CHECKSUM as you said And then in SQL I have created a table for Hash Value as NVARCHAR datatype.

**UDF:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MD5Hash(@input NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hash VARBINARY(16)
    SET @hash = HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST(@input AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
    RETURN UPPER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), @hash, 2))
END
```

;
**SQL Table:**
CREATE TABLE Hash2int (
id INT,
name VARCHAR(100),
hash_value NVARCHAR(32)
);
[image]

[image]
Using the **Update** statement and CAST and CONVERT  function converting  the **NVARCHAR** datatype to **Integer**.

```
UPDATE Hash2int
SET hash_value = CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), hash_value, 0) AS INT);
```

[image]

Comment: hash value is not the same in databricks and t-sql, look at John hash integer value for both cases. Anyway, thank you for the effort.